# How can I jump line while writing a list() to txt?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am working with a code generator and I want to change line after every list of numbers.
I have this:

`(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5)`

I want this:

```
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 

(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 

(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2), 

(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3),

...
```

I am also writing this into a txt file and would like to have the same layout in it.

This is my current code:

```
import itertools

f = open("codes.txt", "w")

listing = list(itertools.product(range(10), repeat=6))

print(listing)

f.write(str(listing) + "\n")
```

Comment: for sublist in list?

Comment: `print(*itertools.product(range(10), repeat=6), sep="\n", file=f)`

Comment: what is the prupose of this file? What are you going to do with it after? Using `f.write(str(whatever))` is usually not the right thing to do

Comment: I just want the data written to the text file and this does it´s purpose. What other method would you suggest? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: What is the *purpose* of doing that? You aren't describing what you want to do without the the file. Are you just creating the file for fun? Or you expect to *read that data from another program?* If so, then this is definitely the wrong approach.

Comment: yes I am in fact going to read it from another program

Comment: @MariusPrakash Then it makes more sense if you store the values in formats that require less effort for reading. like CSV? Currently it has space + parenthesis + ...

Answer (score 2):

I liked the solution suggested by @Andrej Kesely, except that: Unpacking happens all at once, and the functions in `itertools` may create a huge number of items, so it's better not to unpack them but printing them in a loop.

```py
import itertools

with open("codes.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in itertools.product(range(10), repeat=6):
        print(i, file=f)
```